# Nested JavaScript 'for' loops - why doesn't the first loop run the whole length?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let y = i + 1; y < arr.length; y++) {
    for (let x = y + 1; x < arr.length; x++) {
      console.log(`${arr[i]}${arr[y]}${arr[x]} ${i} ${y} ${x}`)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why my first `for` loop will only run until the "e" iteration and stop. So the last line looks like this: `efg 4 5 6`.

From my understanding, it's stopping because the last `for` loop reached its limit, making the second to last also stop, because there's no more code to run, which makes the first one also stop.

So, am I correct in assuming this?

Is it really stopping because the nested `for` loop ran out?

Which means I could do something like, `i < arr.length - 2` and `y < arr.length - 1` and `x < arr.length` and it wouldn't make a difference?

---

After posting I realized that the `console.log` is on the last nested `for` loop, and it reaches the the end before the first, that's why I don't see the output. Which means, it truly doesn't matter how long the first loop runs, since x is going to be two digits ahead.

Comment: Yes - your assumption is correct. Outer loop runs until 6, but inner loops do not run because they fail to pass loop condition, which results in no messages being output. Yes, you can replace it and will make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect to think that the `i` and `y` are stopping... they're not, they will continue to go through each value as you'd expect

It's because when `i` becomes 5, it means that `y` starts at 6 (5 + 1), which means `x` starts at 7 (6 + 1).

And because 7 is not `< arr.length`, the `x` loop doesn't run... so you don't get a console output.

---

If you run the following snippet, I've put a console log just within the `i` loop... so you can see that `i` does go through all the values

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${arr[i]} ${i}`)
  for (let y = i + 1; y < arr.length; y++) {
    for (let x = y + 1; x < arr.length; x++) {
      //console.log(`${arr[i]}${arr[y]}${arr[x]} ${i} ${y} ${x}`)
    }
  }
}
```